# webp animation to gif animation (cli)

Tags: arch-linux, imagemagick, gif, animation, webp

I was surprised today to find apparently how difficult it is to go from a `webp` animation to `gif` animation. My `GIMP 2.8.22` and `ImageMagick 7.0.7-21` on `linux 4.14.13-1-ARCH` don't seem to support the format, and the only tool available in repos seem to be `libwebp 0.4.1` which includes a decode tool that lets you extract individual frames to some image formats, none of them being gif (It's a licensing problem maybe?)

Anyway, I used the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

DELAY=${DELAY:-10}
LOOP=${LOOP:-0}
r=`realpath $1`
d=`dirname $r`
pushd $d > /dev/null
f=`basename $r`
n=`webpinfo -summary $f | grep frames | sed -e 's/.* \([0-9]*\)$/\1/'`
pfx=`echo -n $f | sed -e 's/^\(.*\).webp$/\1/'`
if [ -z $pfx ]; then
    pfx=$f
fi

echo "converting $n frames from $f 
working dir $d
file stem '$pfx'"

for ((i=0; i<$n; i++)); do
    webpmux -get frame $i $f -o $pfx.$i.webp
    dwebp $pfx.$i.webp -o $pfx.$i.png
done

convert $pfx.*.png -delay $DELAY -loop $LOOP $pfx.gif
rm $pfx.[0-9]*.png $pfx.[0-9]*.webp
popd > /dev/null
```

Which creates a gif animation from the extracted frames of the file supplied in the first argument.

I tried it on [this file](https://media.giphy.com/media/2QMJl34Dv9F8A/giphy.gif) and the [resulting file](https://gateway.ipfs.io/ipfs/QmUf8syr2YHHe2ANE9wqgdwLU1UhGidsgn7qcbunLBJxSD) was kind of artifacty. Is it proper form to post in this forum for suggestions of improvement of the procedure/invocations?

And: If there are custom tools for this conversion, please share your knowledge! :)

Comment: This seems like a question better suited for Code Review (still not off topic!)

Comment: I would think keep it here because *nix users wondering about this conversion would have a better change finding it here and thus benefit from the discussion?

Comment: I have the same question as you, and I was happy to find this (+1). You have two answers, but you have not **accepted** either of them. Did the answers not work, did you solve it yourself, lose interest & move on or what...? I don't mean to be nosey, just trying to avoid putting time into this if it doesn't work.

Comment: The best technique I've found so far is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59977561/how-can-i-avoid-dropouts-when-using-imagemagick-mogrify-to-convert-webp-file

Comment: Gimp 2.10.20 supports conversion. see this link on youtube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6T3mp0EoxBA

Answer (score 19):

Running into the same issue myself, I found that using Python and its Pillow library might be the easiest way. Just import it, let it load the image file, and directly save it again with appropriate options.

```py
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('your_file.webp')
im.save('your_file.gif', 'gif', save_all=True, optimize=True, background=0)
```

Tested with Python3.8 and Pillow 8.0.1. You might have to install or upgrade the library first, using e.g. `python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade Pillow`

All on one line to batch convert all `*.webp` files in the current folder to `*.gif` with the same name:

```bsh
for f in *.webp;do echo "$f";python3 -c "from PIL import Image;Image.open('$f').save('${f%.webp}.gif','gif',save_all=True,optimize=True,background=0)";done
```

Note: This answer was inspired by [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52016407/4464570).

Comment: this did the trick nicely

Comment: great answer, though color-wise it reduces quality. Here's a script to convert webp with high quality

https://gist.github.com/nimatrueway/0e743d92056e2c5f995e25b848a1bdcd

Comment: @NiMaThr, thanks man!

Answer (score 8):

Your script works just fine, but you need to zero pad your individual frame names; otherwise it creates the gif with frames in a jumbled order. I fixed that and tried it on a few giphy webp animations (including your example) and the output is what you'd expect.

Below is just your script with two changes. First, an altered `for` loop to zero pad those frame filenames. Second, I added another webpinfo check to grab the frame duration and use that (if > 0) for DELAY (naively assuming that people aren't using variable frame durations):

```
#!/bin/bash

DELAY=${DELAY:-10}
LOOP=${LOOP:-0}
r=`realpath $1`
d=`dirname $r`
pushd $d > /dev/null
f=`basename $r`
n=`webpinfo -summary $f | grep frames | sed -e 's/.* \([0-9]*\)$/\1/'`
dur=`webpinfo -summary $f | grep Duration | head -1 |  sed -e 's/.* \([0-9]*\)$/\1/'`

if (( $dur > 0 )); then
    DELAY = dur
fi

pfx=`echo -n $f | sed -e 's/^\(.*\).webp$/\1/'`
if [ -z $pfx ]; then
    pfx=$f
fi

echo "converting $n frames from $f 
working dir $d
file stem '$pfx'"

for i in $(seq -f "%05g" 1 $n)
do
    webpmux -get frame $i $f -o $pfx.$i.webp
    dwebp $pfx.$i.webp -o $pfx.$i.png
done

convert $pfx.*.png -delay $DELAY -loop $LOOP $pfx.gif
rm $pfx.[0-9]*.png $pfx.[0-9]*.webp
popd > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 7):

I would have used `ffmpeg` for this task. Have a look at [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/556029/how-do-i-convert-a-video-to-gif-using-ffmpeg-with-reasonable-quality) which should give you good results.

I tried with the mp4 of the gif from giphy and obtained this gif below as a result, which looks pretty good in my opinion!

```
mkdir frames
ffmpeg -i giphy.mp4 -vf scale=320:-1:flags=lanczos,fps=10 frames/ffout%03d.png
convert -loop 0 frames/ffout*.png output.gif
```

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem as the OP - I need to convert *animated* **webp-to-gif**. I would like to use `ffmpeg` & was drawn to your answer. But I must be missing something. You *appear* to be converting from **mp4-to-gif**.  If you could enlighten me, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I indeed converted *mp4-to-gif* (as it is possible to download mp4 from giphy). For *webp-to-gif*, you need to extract frames first (you can use the method described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1141049)) using `anim_dump` then use `ffmpeg` to convert it back to a mp4 video (eg. using `ffmpeg -framerate 25 -i dump_%04d.tiff output.mp4`)

Comment: [ffmpeg doesn't support decoding animated webp](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3760)

Answer (score 1):

The bulk of your script can be replaced using the `anim_dump` binary, which is included in the [`libwebp` package](http://downloads.webmproject.org/releases/webp/index.html) along with `webpmux`, `dwebp`, etc.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

for file in /path/to/*.webp; do
    mkdir "$temporaryDirectory.frames"

    # export a webp file into frames;
    # Download the packge directly from the official Google Analytics repository in
    # http://storage.googleapis.com/downloads.webmproject.org/releases/webp/libwebp-1.3.0-linux-x86-64.tar.gz
    anim_dump -folder "$temporaryDirectory.frames" "$file"

    convert "$temporaryDirectory.frames"/*.png -delay 10 -loop 0 "$file.gif"
    /bin/rm -fr "$temporaryDirectory.frames"
done
```